# Does the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k^{\log k}}\right)$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k^{\log k}}\right)$$ this is converge. But how? I think here we use comparison thm.

Comment: Please avoid using `$$` and `\displaystyle` in the title.

Answer (score 10):

Try comparing this series to $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}.$$  Since $\log(x)\geq 2$ for $x\geq e^2$, after throwing out finitely many terms you can prove convergence.

> **Added:** Alternatively, by using the [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), we need only prove the convergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{2^{n^{2}\log2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_k = 1/k^{\log k}$. 
Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} &=& \frac{k^{\log k}}{(k+1)^{\log (k+1)}} \\
&=& \exp \left[\log^2 k - \log^2(k+1)\right].
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Now show 
$\log^2 k < \log^2(k+1)$ for $k\ge 1$ 
and apply the ratio test.